# Generate CRUD RESTful API from data model

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, express, node-orm2

I'm developing single-page app based on Angular, RESTful, Express. To manage database I selected [node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2). My data models are something like:

```
var User = db.define("user", {
    name: String
});
var Order = db.define("order", {
    type: String,
    comment: String
}
// this line will produce methods: Order.getOwner(..), Order.setOwner(..), User.getOrders(..), User.addOrder(..)
Order.hasOne("owner", User, {reverse: 'orders'});
var Offer = db.define("offer",{
    price:  Number
});
// this line will produce methods: Offer.getOrder(..), Offer.setOrder(..), Order.getOffers(..), Order.addOffer(..)
Offer.hasOne("order", Order, {reverse: "offers"});
```

To access this models from Angular fronted (using `$resource`) I created RESTful handlers for my Express app:

```
router.route("/user/:user_id/orders").get(...).post(...)
router.route("/user/:user_id/orders/:order_id").get(...).delete(...)
router.route("/user/:user_id/orders/:order_id/offers").get(...).post(...)
router.route("/user/:user_id/orders/:order_id/offers/:offer_id").get(...).put(...)
```

After that I realized that there is a clear mapping between data model definition and RESTful API implementation.

For example, if I have `Offer.hasOne("order", Order, ...)` I have sub-tree of paths for Offer manipulations under `/user/:user_id/orders/:order_id`. And this sub-tree is standard:

1. `offers").post(...)` - create offer;
2. `offers").get(...)` - to get all offers;
3. `offers/:offer_id").get(...)` - to get concrete offer
4. `offers/:offer_id").put(...)` - to modify concrete offer

It should be possible to define models and than just register them to be handled by RESTful API.

Is there any existing frameworks for this case?

**UPDATE**

The business logic operations I'll implement as PUT actions with arguments.

Comment: Exactly what Loopback does: check it out at http://loopback.io

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. My plan is to have two bunches of handlers: the first is for dummy operations like CRUD (generate by some framework), the second is manually-implemented for business-specific operations for concrete objects isolated into PUT handler. For first bunch Loopback is perfect but I'll get troubles with the second.

Comment: Even by implementing [remote methods](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods)?

Comment: By most of the applications there is no clear mapping between the resources and the data models. If you need a new operation than you have to use an existing HTTP method on an "entity" resource or on a "virtual" resource. What you want to do is map the entities to the "entity" resources and the CRUD operations to the HTTP methods, which can be done, but most of the applications have "virtual" resources too, since they do more than just CRUD. So I think you are missing a service layer.

Comment: I don't recommend you to use hierarchical URLs, use flat URLs, like: `/offers/:offer_id` instead. Your responses should contain hyperlinks (if you don't use a custom vendor specific MIME type), which contain operation templates: METHOD + URI-template + link-META + properties + properties-META, where only META is used by the client to understand what the hyperlink does and how to fill in the missing properties. There is a [hydra middleware library](https://github.com/bergos/hydra-middleware) for js under development if you want to learn more about REST and [hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/).